# Necesito imprimir desde mi programa ejecutado como servicio de Windows

Tags: java, windows, servicio, print, imprimir

Tengo un programa creado en Java que obtiene un PDF y lo imprime. Para imprimirlo uso ghostscript:

```
public static void print(String nomImpresora, String rutaNombreArchivo, int cantVia) throws Exception {
    String cmd;
    cmd = "gswin64c -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=" + cantVia + " -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dNoCancel -sOutputFile=\"\\\\spool\\" + nomImpresora + "\" " + rutaNombreArchivo;
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        Log.addLog(Log.tipoMensaje.InfoSis, "Se envio a Imprimir a la impresora: " + Conf.o().getNomImpresora());
        Log.addLog(Log.tipoMensaje.InfoSis, "Imprime eFacturaPrint: S, Formato: " + Conf.o().getForamtoImpresion() + ", " + Conf.o().getNumVias() + " vias");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.addLog(Log.tipoMensaje.ErrorGenerico, "Error al intentar imprimir con gs: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (p != null) {
            p.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Desde Netbeans, o ejecutando el programa desde consola funciona perfectamente.

Lo que sucede es que este programa debe ejecutarse en segundo plano al inicio del sistema. Por lo que primeramente cree un bat que ejecuta el programa y lo configuré en el programador de tareas. Debido a que el programador de tareas no lo detiene ni inicia he investigado que lo mejor es wrappearlo, por lo cual he usado JSmooth.
Creo el servicio, lo instalo, funciona, con la excepción de que no imprime. Para mejor del caso no capturo excepciones.

He intentado enviar directo a la impresora pero al ser un PDF mi impresora no lo interpreta e imprime cualquier texto.

Agradezco su interes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, investigando mucho, encontré otra solución para imprimir. Utilizo la librería de Apache PDDocument. Un requisito indispensable es eliminar todas las salidas y realizar el log en archivo de text. También he separado el programa en dos. Un modulo que manipula los datos y crea el pdf. El otro solamente imprime invocando System.Runtime. Este segundo módulo tampoco puede tener salidas en pantalla.

En internet van a encontrar mucho acerca de no realizar servicios windows que impriman, ya que la API de windows especifica que no es aconsejable. En mi experiencia, con jdk 1.7, PDDocument y JSmooth lo he logrado luego de muchas pruebas.